# how to enable json store in worklight hybrid xcode app

Tags: xcode, ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I am working in worklight hybrid app,in worklight documentation they have mentioned that we can enable JSON store form eclipse project, how to enable JSON store from x-code application?

Answer (score 0):

In Worklight 6.1, JSONStore support is available only for **Hybrid** Worklight apps.
If by "x-code application" you are referring to a fully **native** app - this is not available in this version of Worklight.

To enable JSONStore support in Worklight 6.1 Hybrid apps, [follow these steps](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_enabling_jsonstore.html?lang=en).

---

In Worklight 6.2, to be released next month (June 2014), JSONStore support [has been extended also to native apps](http://www.websphereusergroup.org/go/article/view/articles/265479/impact_2014%3a_mobile_strategy_and_ibm_worklight_6.2). Instructions on how to add it will be provided once Worklight 6.2 is released.

Comment: I have created a native ios component(x-code environment) within that worklight hybrid app,i am working on javascript functionalities in that ios component,i need to enable JSON store from that ios app.

Comment: Like I wrote, there is no JSONStore support in native; doesn't matter if it is a component or fully native.

Comment: Idan,i have created x-code app from worklight hybrid app,is it possible to convert x-code app to eclipse project using worklight environment?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking and it doesn't sound like it relates to this question anymore.

Comment: I am going to use JSON store for web portions only,thing is that Before generating iPhone app from worklight hybrid app i did not enable JSON store,is there any way to enable that in iPhone app.

Comment: No. You must go to the Application Descriptor Editor, select the iPhone environment > Optional features > JSONStore and re-build the project. Then JSONStore will be added to the project.

Comment: Idan,i don't have that eclipse project,i have only iPhone app,so it is not possible to build the project again?thats why i am asking is it possible to enable JSON store from x-code app itself?

Comment: Where is the Worklight project in Eclipse? Do you mean you received the generated iPhone project that was created in Eclipse? well, no, it must be added in eclipse.

Comment: yes i have the iPhone project only,so only in eclipse we can enable JSON store.Thanks Idan

Comment: Again one doubt,is it possible to put back the iPhone app to eclipse worklight environment and build the app again?

Comment: No, because the Worklight project and iPhone project are different things.

Comment: can u give me a solution for this situation?i need to use JSON store for web portions alone,in this iPhone app generated from worklight app ?

Comment: I don't understand why you do not have your Eclipse project anyway - it is not an optional thing, you MUST have it. There is where you write your web code, the app - the HTML, JS, CSS, not in Xcode. So no, you must add it to your Eclipse project and re-generate the Xcode project.

Comment: It sounds to me like you do not understand how Worklight works and I again tell you to read the documentation.